# Css triangle is nice Css blur is nice, now how do I get the two together?

Tags: html, css

my issue is that the blur applies to the entire square of the div not the triangle.

If this can be done via svg instead, I'm interested.

```css
html {
  background-image: url("https://www.terra.bzh/sites/terra/files/styles/normal_size/public/beverages-3105631_1920_2.jpg.webp?itok=Rf5o2Hr0");
  background-size: cover;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50px 0 0 50px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FF000060;
  backdrop-filter: blur(0.2rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `clip-path` instead.

```css
html {
  background-image: url("https://www.terra.bzh/sites/terra/files/styles/normal_size/public/beverages-3105631_1920_2.jpg.webp?itok=Rf5o2Hr0");
  background-size: cover;
}

.triangle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #FF000060;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(0.2rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Another idea with `mask`

```css
html {
  background-image: url("https://www.terra.bzh/sites/terra/files/styles/normal_size/public/beverages-3105631_1920_2.jpg.webp?itok=Rf5o2Hr0");
  background-size: cover;
}

.triangle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #FF000060;
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(to top right, #000 50%, transparent 50%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(0.2rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: @doğukan out of clip-path and mask, which is most performant?

Comment: @tatsu we can not talk about the performance of static properties. but I'd suggest using mask because with the mask you can have control on position and size. like this: `-webkit-mask: linear-gradient(to top right, #000 50%, transparent 50%) 50% 0 / 40px 100% no-repeat;`